# Converting from width to background-width in Less for sprites within CSS class

Tags: css, less, gruntjs

I'm new to advanced CSS and I've been following [this tutorial](http://emlyn.net/posts/spritesmith-tutorial) for generating sprites using gruntjs, spritesmith and less. I'm stuck on how to solve the following problem. Firstly, I generate a .less file containing the information of each image inside the sprite. It looks something like this:

```
  @mobile_logout-x: 1586px;
  @mobile_logout-y: 0px;
  @mobile_logout-offset-x: -1586px;
  @mobile_logout-offset-y: 0px;
  @mobile_logout-width: 256px;
  @mobile_logout-height: 256px;
```

Using grunt-contrib-less I can now use the following to get the sprite into my target css:

**Less template**

```
.mobile_logout {
    .sprite(@mobile_logout);
}
```

**Result**

```
.mobile_logout {
  background-image: url(images-mobile/mobile-sprite.png);
  background-position: -1586px 0px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
```

This would be fine if I wanted to use this directly in the HTML, but I'd like to specify this as part of another CSS class. An example would be:

```
.myTestButton {
  background-image: url(images-mobile/mobile-sprite.png);
  background-position: -1586px 0px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  color: white;
  background-size: 1.3em 1.3em;
  background-position: top right;
}
```

The problem is at this stage I can't find a way to get the width and height to be represented as **background-width** and **background-height**, which is where I am looking to get to.

I've tried changing the values in the sprite.less file to match what I'm looking for, but have found that was a hack that didn't work. Another option I have been considering is having a mixin to return the correct item with the width translated, but because these are generated from less I couldn't get that to fly either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting this I looked into where the sprite function came from and found my answer in the generated sprite.less file:

```
  .sprite-width(@sprite) {
    width: ~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[4]`;
  }

  .sprite-height(@sprite) {
    height: ~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[5]`;
  }
```

The sprite.less file is generated using a [mustache template](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html). In order to solve my problem in Spritesmith you can specify a mustache template. It was also incorrect that I was looking at background-width and the property I needed was background-size. My attempts at inlining also failed, and I should have been looking at using a div rather than sizing the sprite component.